# sonata admin datagrid (list view with filters and pagers) for a joined query of linked entities?

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, inner-join, sonata-admin

What I want is to create a **Datagrid in sonata admin** without it being a real CRUD. 
My data is a **joined query of different entities**, on top of which I **need to modify the result** to show it in a table. 
What I would love is to be able to use all the functionality for the pager and the filters without the "edit" capabilities and with a custom "array of arrays".
I have not found how to solve this with the normal sonata docs, if this has to happen outside of sonata how do I embed it in sonata. It just seems so wrong to use a different bundle and then just map the css to look the same. Surely someone has needed this before.

Comment: can't you just remove all routes (except list) of your Admin ?

Comment: Sure. But I don't have clear model entity but a query. Or are you implying that I should create an entity of the query? Is that possible? I have read you can create read only entities for views but they seem to have some problems. And how do I wire up my model entity?

Comment: You can create a view for your query, and create a readOnly Doctrine entity for it. Never tried to bind a Sonata Admin for it...